multiple lines unexpectedly highlighted in line chart with ggiraph
I am trying to follow the tutorial on youtube, but my dataset shows a different result with the expection.
Here is my code demo:
library(shiny)
library(ggiraph)

tab <- tabPanel(
  title='Analysis',
  mainPanel(girafeOutput("plotLineChart"))
)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title='title',
  tab
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plotLineChart <- renderGirafe({
    
    avg_price_by_region_year <- data.frame(
        Regionname = c("Eastern Metropolitan", "Eastern Metropolitan", "Eastern Metropolitan",
                        "Eastern Victoria", "Eastern Victoria",
                        "Northern Metropolitan", "Northern Metropolitan", "Northern Metropolitan",
                        "Northern Victoria", "Northern Victoria",
                        "South-Eastern Metropolitan", "South-Eastern Metropolitan", "South-Eastern Metropolitan",
                        "Southern Metropolitan", "Southern Metropolitan", "Southern Metropolitan",
                        "Western Metropolitan", "Western Metropolitan", "Western Metropolitan",
                        "Western Victoria", "Western Victoria"),
        Year = as.factor(c(2016, 2017, 2018,
                            2017, 2018,
                            2016, 2017, 2018,
                            2017, 2018,
                            2016, 2017, 2018,
                            2016, 2017, 2018,
                            2016, 2017, 2018,
                            2017, 2018)),
        AvgPrice = c(1109674.0, 1158106.8, 1240989.0,
                    655853.2, 686400.0,
                    887806.8, 868906.8, 879591.4,
                    577051.3, 636326.1,
                    911577.0, 931217.6, 891513.5,
                    1400595.8, 1522924.0, 1953786.1,
                    877687.7, 876664.7, 886901.0,
                    437528.6, 482000.0)
        )

    obj <- ggplot(avg_price_by_region_year, aes(x=Year, y=AvgPrice, group=Regionname, color=Regionname)) +
      geom_line_interactive(aes(data_id=Regionname)) + 
      geom_point_interactive() + 
      labs(x="Year", y="Average Price") +
      scale_color_viridis_d()
    girafe(ggobj=obj)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

When I hover or select a category of line, there should be only one line in chart would be highlighted, but some other lines unexpectedly highlighted as well. For example, when I hove on 'Southern Metropolitan', the 'Western Metropolitan' and 'Western Victoria' will also highlighted.
error example
I know the interactive element should be controlled by data_id, but set it as Regionname should be right, I can not find any other problem. Please help me. I appreciate.

After some experimenting this looks like a bug to me. The reason why multiple lines get highlighted is that they are assigned an NA value under the hood. You can make that visible by adding tooltip = Regionname.

Thank you Stefan, I think there is a bug when x-axis has few values, when I add one year error would be fixed.

Just as a reference. The issue was already reported on GH: https://github.com/davidgohel/ggiraph/issues/299
